# Swap axes of a 3D image in nilearn/numpy

Tags: numpy, nibabel, nilearn

I am working with some neuroimaging data and my dimensions for a scan is (100, 150, 100). I am currently working with the nibabel formatted file.

Is there a nice way to swap the axes? For example, I want my image to be (100, 100, 150). I would preferable want this in the nibabel format, but if need be, I can get the image to a numpy ndarray and then do the work there as well. In this case, is there a nice way of doing this in numpy?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: why to do that? is it (X,Y,Z) now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using numpy use:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.swapaxes(arr, 1, 2)
```

This will swap axis 1 and 2 (which are 2nd and 3rd dimension with 150 and 100 size respectively).

Example code:

```
arr = np.zeros((100,150,100))
arr = np.swapaxes(arr, 1, 2)
print(arr.shape)
```

output:

```
(100, 100, 150)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.swapaxes` as mentioned in Ehsan's answer, which swaps two axes. You can also use [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), which allows you to change two or more axes, in any desired order. E.g.:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.empty((4, 5, 6))
>>> data.shape
(4, 5, 6)
>>> np.transpose(data, axes=(1, 2, 0)).shape
(5, 6, 4)
```