# How to swap 2 dimensions in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-image

I have a 4 dimensionnal set of data coming from a Tiff file.

```
image_stack = io.imread(path, plugin='tifffile')
print(image_stack.shape)
>>> (21, 10, 1331, 1126)
```

So the last 2 Dimensions are the images resolutions.
The 10 is because I have 10 slices of the same image (over the z axis) at a given time
And 21 because all of those images are taken every second.

How can I swap the 21 and 10 dimensions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping the dimensions of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943379/swapping-the-dimensions-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609319/swap-axes-of-a-3d-image-in-nilearn-numpy/61609457#61609457

Answer (score 3):

You can just swap the two first axes with [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
a = np.random.rand(21, 10, 1331, 1126)
a.swapaxes(1,0).shape
# (10, 21, 1331, 1126)
```

Or move the second axis backwards with [`rollaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
np.rollaxis(a, 1).shape
# (10, 21, 1331, 1126)
```